# Write to protected file

Tags: c#, service

i wish to write to a protected text file note this content is important.
Can i write to a file to keep it protected i am going to use encryption
but do not wish anyone to read the content of the file. I have tried to
use File.WriteText? but the problem is that the file gets written then
unused so anyone can read the content.

Protection eg. Like the SAM file

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by 'protected'.  Update your question to say who should and who should not be able to read your file.

Comment: Did you mean to specify rights on the file or just that no one is able to open the file from Explorer and only your program can read it?

Comment: Hi mates i mean so only i can read it Thanks:>

Comment: so only my application can read the file

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Dotnet framework, [TextFile attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are available in c# will enable you to keep the file encrypted and readonly. The write protection can be done using [FileIOPermissionAccesss](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionaccess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  If current user is administrator then he will able to give protect and delete permissions for particular can be given to the file. Below is sample code for adding permission.

```
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);    
var writePermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, filename);
permissionSet.AddPermission(writePermission);

if (permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
{
    using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fstream))
    {
        // try catch block for write permissions 
        writer.WriteLine("sometext");


    }
}
else
{
    //perform some recovery action here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced similar problem, instead in my case the problem was the
   data in my file should be visible to anyone even to the admin user,
   and for every time the application runs the previous data should be
   replaced by the new one.

Here's my code

```
    string pathfile = @"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Filepath.txt";  
  if    (File.Exists(pathfile)) 
   {

                     File.Delete(pathfile);


                 }
                 if (!File.Exists(pathfile))
                 {


                     using (FileStream fs = File.Create(pathfile))

                     {
                         Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("Your Text Here");

                         fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);


                         FileSecurity fsec = File.GetAccessControl(pathfile);
                         fsec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone",
                         FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
                         File.SetAccessControl(pathfile, fsec);

                     }


                     }
```